# P2.inf: refer update sites based on location

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

I have developed an RCP application and I am providing p2 update functionality.

In my p2.inf i am providing the url for update site. I don't want user to add any site so I have disabled an option to add a site. My p2.inf looks like:

```
instructions.configure=\
  addRepository(type:0,location:http${#58}//blrupdates.com/Updates);\
  addRepository(type:1,location:http${#58}//blrupdates.com/Updates);
```

if user location is bangalore, RCP application should go to brlupdates.com, if user location is chennai then RCP application should look for update at chnupdates.com.

how to add another repository location in p2.inf?

-Priyank

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the repository programatically. The following solution is taken from [here](http://coopology.com/2012/08/eclipse-rcp-setting-p2-repositories-update-sites-programmatically-for-when-p2-inf-fails/). Another solution, that I'm not sure it would work is to use redirection. You define one p2 repository and then you redirect the user to the location based repository.

```
import org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement;
import org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.ElementUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class P2Util {
  private static String UPDATE_SITE = "http://www.example.com/update_site";

  public static void setRepositories() throws InvocationTargetException {
    try {
      final MetadataRepositoryElement element = new MetadataRepositoryElement(null, new URI(UPDATE_SITE), true);
      ElementUtils.updateRepositoryUsingElements(new MetadataRepositoryElement[] {element}, null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new InvocationTargetException(e);
    }
  }
}
```